Angular 18 - Ag-grid - Double Scrollbars (operates as one)
Using Ag-Grid to display a grid of information. I have used ag-grid it before, but this is my first time with Angular 18. When the data is displayed with more rows that visible, the scrollbars appear, but they appear doubled. They work at the same time, scrolling through the rows, but I cannot figure out why I have duplicate scrollbars for a single data grid. This is my code.
<hr/>
    <ag-grid-angular id="dataTbl"
                     style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                     class="ag-theme-balham"
                     [rowData]="dgData"
                     [columnDefs]="colHeadData"
                     [defaultColDef]="colDefaults"
                     [animateRows]="true"
                     (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
                     (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>

I've placed it in a DIV tag, and removed it from the DIV tag, there is no change. While in the DIV, I've included in the CSS "overflow: hidden;", but no change. Wondering if anyone else has come across this behavior or have a possible solution.
Here is the right side of my datagrid.
Double scrollbar
Since it is operating correctly, I will continue development as I am on a timeline, but would like to remove it if at all possible. Thanks in advance.
Extra note: Using the community version of ag-grid, version 32.0.2.
Steps I have tried.

Placed in DIV and used css to hide all scrollbars.
Removed from DIV.
Used CSS to control scrollbars on Ag-Grid.


I've downloaded the latest version of ag-grid community (33.0) and still have the double scrollbars.  Any time I use the grid, I get the bars.  I've tried everything from rebuilding to updating, and nothing is working.  Does anyone have any suggestions?
